# NSInvalidArgumentException - Attempt to insert nil object from objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, crash

I had the error below:

```
'*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

it happens when I try to save texts from textfields using **saveInBackground**  or other kind of saving method of Parse. Because code is little, all code is pasted below:

```
@IBAction func onSave(_ sender: Any) {
    let profile = PFObject(className: "Info")

    profile["preferredName"] = nameTextField.text!
    profile["major"] = majorTextField.text!
    profile["introduction"] = bioTextView.text!

    let segmentIndex = yearSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex
    UserDefaults.standard.set(segmentIndex, forKey: "segmentIndex")
    profile["year"] = yearSegmented.titleForSegment(at: segmentIndex)!

    print(profile.allKeys) // print keys in profile
    print(profile.value(forKey: "introduction")!, profile.value(forKey: "major")!,
    profile.value(forKey: "year")!, profile.value(forKey: "preferredName")!) // print values in profile
    
    profile.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in // line where the error happens
        if success {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasProfile")
            print("profile saved")
        } else {
            print("failed to save profile")
        }
    })
```

This is how Parse IOS Guide told me about how to save objects:

```
let gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
gameScore.saveInBackground { (succeeded, error)  in
if (succeeded) {
    // The object has been saved.
} else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
}
```

}

I tested if any content in profile is nil, but all keys and values are there and can be printed. I don't see anything nil here, so I cannot understand this error. If anyone could shed some light to enlighten me, I would be be very grateful for this.

In case anyone needs the stack trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803f25e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 236
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018019813c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804775b4 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180474fc4 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithCapacity:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001802ef138 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 184
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001803dddec +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 44
6   Parse                               0x0000000104eda478 -[PFTaskQueue enqueue:] + 380
7   Parse                               0x0000000104e78b2c -[PFObject saveInBackground] + 148
8   Parse                               0x0000000104e78c1c -[PFObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:] + 68
9   StudyMate                           0x00000001041c59bc $s9StudyMate18EditViewControllerC6onSaveyyypF + 7276
10  StudyMate                           0x00000001041c5fe4 $s9StudyMate18EditViewControllerC6onSaveyyypFTo + 68
11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184d81fa0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001842a7714 -[UIBarButtonItem _triggerActionForEvent:] + 176
13  UIKitCore                           0x000000018427fe24 __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 36
14  UIKitCore                           0x000000018427fcd8 -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] + 168
15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184d81fa0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184680bd8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 124
17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184680fc0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 352
18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184681010 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 432
19  UIKitCore                           0x000000018467f8e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 516
20  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184dc0af0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 1104
21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184dc25d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4332
22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184d9a390 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 784
23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184e286f4 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 7520
24  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184e2a770 __processEventQueue + 6764
25  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184e22760 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 184
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180360820 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180360720 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018035fab0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018035a004 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180359804 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
31  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018c23660c GSEventRunModal + 160
32  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184d7bd2c -[UIApplication _run] + 992
33  UIKitCore                           0x0000000184d808c8 UIApplicationMain + 112
34  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00000001b6766224 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 100
35  StudyMate                           0x00000001041c7a9c $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 104
36  StudyMate                           0x00000001041c7a24 $s9StudyMate11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 44
37  StudyMate                           0x00000001041c7b20 main + 28
38  dyld                                0x0000000104501cd8 start_sim + 20
39  ???                                 0x0000000104451088 0x0 + 4366602376
40  ???                                 0xb23a000000000000 0x0 + 12842577287400390656
```

Comment: So what does `saveInBackground` do? Without showing the code for that function it will be hard to tell whats wrong.

Comment: It's a method from the 'Parse' pod. It basically saves the PFObject to Parse server asynchronously and executes the given callback block. the interface works as  'NSMutableDictionary' as described by Parse official. But sorry I don't know how they did that exactly

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/450 ?

Comment: In https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/blob/2e4242c683e645a7d78ff37dd34398119178c0c5/Parse/Parse/Internal/PFTaskQueue.m I see `@[oldTail, task]`, so I guess that `task` is nil, and causes the crash. But it would need digging on why `taskStart()` returns `nil`...

Comment: Oh I see, I initialized Parse in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. it works after I initialized it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Thanks!